# Problem creating dll in Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, dll, java-native-interface

I know Java, but I'm completely new to C ++ and Visual Studio. I am trying to build a dll file from two source files (cpp and h). I need this in order to use native functions in a Java application (JNI/JNA). This is a kind of global key hook that should remap keyboard buttons, I hope.

But when I paste in the source code, there are places where it is highlighted in red and it says:

**CPP file**

**"Cannot open source file w32api.h"**. I am using VS with Russian language so I translated it.

[image]

**"error-type" JNIEXPORT  This declaration does not contain a storage class or type specifier**

[image]

**H file**

**"error-type" JNIEXPORT  This declaration does not contain a storage class or type specifier**

[image]

And here is source code:

*RemapKeys.h*

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_cooltrickshome_RemapKeys */

#ifndef _Included_com_cooltrickshome_RemapKeys
#define _Included_com_cooltrickshome_RemapKeys
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    /*
     * Class:     com_cooltrickshome_RemapKeys
     * Method:    remapPassedKeys
     * Signature: (II)V
     */
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_cooltrickshome_RemapKeys_remapPassedKeys
    (JNIEnv*, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

*RemapKeys.cpp*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <w32api.h>
#include "RemapKeys.h"

static HHOOK handleKeyboardHook = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;
DWORD oldKey = NULL;
DWORD newKey = NULL;

static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (p->vkCode == oldKey)
        {
            switch (wParam) {

            case WM_KEYDOWN: {
                keybd_event(newKey, 0x1D, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
                break;
            }

            case WM_KEYUP: {
                keybd_event(newKey, 0x1D, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                break;
            }

            default:
                wParam = WM_SYSKEYDOWN;
                break;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(handleKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_cooltrickshome_RemapKeys_remapPassedKeys
(JNIEnv*, jobject, jint oldValue, jint newValue) {

    /* printf("Your message here\n");
       fflush(stdout);*/

    oldKey = oldValue;
    newKey = newValue;

    hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    handleKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, hInst, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

What I did wrong? Can anyone help me with that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Those header files are not in the default include path so you will need to include them as well (download them in case you don't have them)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185241/7227724

Comment: @magmine Ok, thanks

Comment: Not in any specific place since you just need the path, the link I shared might help you

Comment: @magmine I got rid from JNIEXPORT error by adding JDK into C/C++ settings. The only place still red is #include <w32api.h>. It's not default too? I don't know where can I find it..

Comment: @magmine I changed it too #include "pch.h". So it was built successfully. I hope it gonna work :)